# Unblessed Hashref error

Tags: perl, moose, hashref

I have been learning Moose and am struggling with my tests, I keep getting the error message

```
Type of argument to keys on reference must be unblessed hashref or arrayref at ./GO2.t line 40, <DATA> chunk 1.
```

I've included my .t script, I'm not sure how to fix this error and haven't found any answers to what exactly an unblessed hashref is. I didn't include everything from DATA, just a few iterations. 
I'm thinking that I am calling the hash incorrectly

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use GO2;
use MooseX::FollowPBP;

use Test::More tests => 44;

#Initialize $_ to prevent warnings in redefinition of $/ as RegEx
$_ = '';
local $/ = /\[Term\]|\[Typedef\]/;

while (<DATA>) {

    # Remove end-of-line characters
    chomp;

    # parse the record using a regular expression
    my $longGoDesc = $_;

    #Create a new GO object
    my $go = GO2->new( 'longGoDesc' => $longGoDesc);

    # ok is a test function that prints ok if the test is true, and
    ok( defined $go->get_id() );
    ok( defined $go->get_def() );
    ok( defined $go->get_name() );
    ok( defined $go->get_namespace() );

    # Initialize is_a counter
    my $isaCount = 0;

    #Loop through the is_a array reference
    foreach my $isaRef ( keys $go->{is_as} ) {
 #Make sure the is_a is defined
            ok( $go->get_is_as()->[$isaRef] );

            #Increment is_a counter
            $isaCount++;
    }

    #Make sure at least one is_a
    ok( $isaCount > 0 );

    # Initialize alt_id counter
    my $altIdCount = 0;

    # Check for alt_id
#       if ( defined $go->{alt_ids} ) {

            #Loop through is_a
            foreach my $altIdRef ( keys $go->{alt_ids} ) {
                    ok( $go->get_alt_ids()->[$altIdRef] );

                    # Increment alt_id counter
                    $altIdCount++;


    }

    #Make sure at least one alt_id
    ok( $altIdCount > 0 );
}

# Indicate that tests are done
done_testing();

# Everything below __END__ is treated as input for the DATA filehandle.
 __END__
[Term]
id: GO:2001315
name: UDP-4-deoxy-4-formamido-beta-L-arabinopyranose biosynthetic process
namespace: biological_process
alt_id: GO:0019901
def: "The chemical reactions and pathways resulting in the formation of a UDP-4-deoxy-4-formamido-beta-L-arabinopyranose." [CHEBI:47027, GOC:yaf, UniPathway:UPA00032]
synonym: "UDP-4-deoxy-4-formamido-beta-L-arabinopyranose anabolism" EXACT [GOC:obol]
synonym: "UDP-4-deoxy-4-formamido-beta-L-arabinopyranose biosynthesis" EXACT [GOC:obol]
synonym: "UDP-4-deoxy-4-formamido-beta-L-arabinopyranose formation" EXACT [GOC:obol]
synonym: "UDP-4-deoxy-4-formamido-beta-L-arabinopyranose synthesis" EXACT [GOC:obol]
is_a: GO:0009226 ! nucleotide-sugar biosynthetic process
is_a: GO:0046349 ! amino sugar biosynthetic process
is_a: GO:2001313 ! UDP-4-deoxy-4-formamido-beta-L-arabinopyranose metabolic process

[Term]
id: GO:2001316
name: kojic acid metabolic process
namespace: biological_process
alt_id: GO:0019902
def: "The chemical reactions and pathways involving kojic acid." [CHEBI:43572, GOC:di]
synonym: "5-hydroxy-2-(hydroxymethyl)-4H-pyran-4-one metabolic process" EXACT [CHEBI:43572, GOC:obol]
synonym: "5-hydroxy-2-(hydroxymethyl)-4H-pyran-4-one metabolism" EXACT [CHEBI:43572, GOC:obol]
synonym: "C6H6O4 metabolic process" RELATED [CHEBI:43572, GOC:obol]
synonym: "C6H6O4 metabolism" RELATED [CHEBI:43572, GOC:obol]
synonym: "kojic acid metabolism" EXACT [GOC:obol]
is_a: GO:0034308 ! primary alcohol metabolic process
is_a: GO:0042180 ! cellular ketone metabolic process
is_a: GO:0046483 ! heterocycle metabolic process
is_a: GO:1901360 ! organic cyclic compound metabolic process

[Term]
id: GO:2001317
name: kojic acid biosynthetic process
namespace: biological_process
alt_id: GO:0019903
def: "The chemical reactions and pathways resulting in the formation of kojic acid." [CHEBI:43572, GOC:di]
synonym: "5-hydroxy-2-(hydroxymethyl)-4H-pyran-4-one anabolism" EXACT [CHEBI:43572, GOC:obol]
synonym: "5-hydroxy-2-(hydroxymethyl)-4H-pyran-4-one biosynthesis" EXACT [CHEBI:43572, GOC:obol]
synonym: "5-hydroxy-2-(hydroxymethyl)-4H-pyran-4-one biosynthetic process" EXACT [CHEBI:43572, GOC:obol]
synonym: "5-hydroxy-2-(hydroxymethyl)-4H-pyran-4-one formation" EXACT [CHEBI:43572, GOC:obol]
synonym: "5-hydroxy-2-(hydroxymethyl)-4H-pyran-4-one synthesis" EXACT [CHEBI:43572, GOC:obol]
synonym: "C6H6O4 anabolism" RELATED [CHEBI:43572, GOC:obol]
synonym: "C6H6O4 biosynthesis" RELATED [CHEBI:43572, GOC:obol]
synonym: "C6H6O4 biosynthetic process" RELATED [CHEBI:43572, GOC:obol]
synonym: "C6H6O4 formation" RELATED [CHEBI:43572, GOC:obol]
synonym: "C6H6O4 synthesis" RELATED [CHEBI:43572, GOC:obol]
synonym: "kojic acid anabolism" EXACT [GOC:obol]
synonym: "kojic acid biosynthesis" EXACT [GOC:obol]
synonym: "kojic acid formation" EXACT [GOC:obol]
synonym: "kojic acid synthesis" EXACT [GOC:obol]
is_a: GO:0018130 ! heterocycle biosynthetic process
is_a: GO:0034309 ! primary alcohol biosynthetic process
is_a: GO:0042181 ! ketone biosynthetic process
is_a: GO:1901362 ! organic cyclic compound biosynthetic process
is_a: GO:2001316 ! kojic acid metabolic process
synonym: "Roundabout signalling pathway involved in muscle cell chemotaxis toward tendon cell" EXACT [GOC:obol]
synonym: "Roundabout signalling pathway involved in muscle cell chemotaxis towards tendon cell" EXACT [GOC:obol]
is_a: GO:0035385 ! Roundabout signaling pathway
relationship: part_of GO:0036061 ! muscle cell chemotaxis toward tendon cell

[Term]
id: GO:2001284
name: regulation of BMP secretion
namespace: biological_process
alt_id: GO:0019904
def: "Any process that modulates the frequency, rate or extent of BMP secretion." [GOC:sart]
synonym: "regulation of BMP protein secretion" EXACT [GOC:obol]
synonym: "regulation of bone morphogenetic protein secretion" EXACT [GOC:obol]
is_a: GO:0010646 ! regulation of cell communication
is_a: GO:0023051 ! regulation of signaling
```

Comment: Try `keys %{ $go->{is_as} }` if it is a hash reference, or just `@{ $go->{is_as} }` if it is an array reference.

Comment: `local $/ = /\[Term\]|\[Typedef\]/;` doesn't set `$/` to a regex. It matches the regex against `$_` and assigns the boolean result to `$/` (effectively `"1"` or `""`).

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Comment: You're not supposed to access object internals directly (`->{...}`), especially not with Moose.

Comment: If you just want a count, `my $isaCount = @{ $go->get_is_as };` (assuming the rest of your code is correct (I'd have to see GO2.pm to be sure)).

Comment: `for my $is_a (@{ $go->get_is_as }) { ok( $is_a ); }`

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html

Comment: All those `get_foo` accessors are odd. I assume this is done by MooseX::FollowPBP? The usual style is `foo` accessors with no `get_` or `set_` prefix. (Also, large chunks of PBP are at least questionable or outright bad advice.)

Comment: Your `$/` code happens to work because you set `$_` to an empty string, which doesn't match `/\[Term\]|\[Typedef\]/`, so it returns a boolean false value, which (when stringified) turns into the empty string, `""`. Setting `$/` to an empty string means to read whole paragraphs (and `chomp` will remove all trailing newlines in this mode).

Comment: `foreach my $is_a ( @{ $go->get_is_as() } ) {  ok(defined $is_a); $altIdCount++; }`

Comment: Note that setting `$/` to a regex pattern won't do what you want. It will split the input on the literal string you have provided, and since your pattern doesn't exist in your data you will simply read all of the data at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keys($ref)` was an experimental feature that has been abandoned. You shouldn't be using it. You must pass an hash (`keys(%...)`) or an array (`keys(@...)`) to `keys`.

---

To get the keys of a referenced array:

```
keys(@{ $ref })
```

Or simply:

```
0 .. $#{ $ref }
```

---

Of course, there's the issue of you accessing the internals of the object. Your code should probably be:

```
my $is_as_s = $go->get_is_as();
my $isaCount = @$is_as_s;

for my $is_as ( @$is_as_s ) {
   ok($is_as);
}
```